# Consolidate a single list of classes

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a list of classes which contains an event name, timestamp, and a duration (timespan). There are many duplicate event names.  I would like to consolidate them by event name and add their durations and keep the earliest timestamp, unless the event has a certain name. i.e., remove duplicate event names, add durations for like event names, and keep the earliest timestamp from the even names.

Is there a better way of doing this? Possibly with Linq?

Here's what I've tried, which doesn't seem to correctly consolidate (there are still duplicates but fewer of them)

The class:

```
public class eventRecords
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}
```

My attempt:

```
// allEventList is already sorted by TimeStamp, so my thinking is adding
// the first occurrence of an event to newList will keep the earliest
// TimeStamp in eventRecrods for that event
// Also - the duplicates are almost all consecutive in allEventList

var newList = new List<eventRecords>();
for (int ii = 0; ii < allEventList.Count; ii++ )
{
    newList.Add(allEventList[ii]);
    if((ii + 1) < allEventList.Count && allEventList[ii] != keyword)
    {
        if(allEventList[ii].Event == allEventList[ii+1].Event)
        {
            newList.Last().Duration = newList.Last().Duration+ allEventList[ii + 1].Duration; 
            ii = ii + 1;
        }

    }

}
```

For example, if allEventList contains:

```
Event = "Action 1", TimeStamp = 08:00, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
Event = "Action 1", TimeStamp = 09:00, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
Event = "Action 1", TimeStamp = 10:00, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
Event = "KeyWord", TimeStamp = 11:00, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
Event = "Action 2", TimeStamp = 12:00, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
Event = "Action 2", TimeStamp = 13:00, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```

newList should contain:

```
Event = "Action 1", TimeStamp = 08:00, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
Event = "KeyWord", TimeStamp = 11:00, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
Event = "Action 2", TimeStamp = 12:00, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This can definitely be done with linq, but I am not totally clear on how you want this data to be aggregated. Could you add an example with some sample data to your post?

Comment: thanks JohnSaunders.  I updated with an example @pquest.

Comment: @Jamiec beat me back to it. That will work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This bit is fairly easy

> I would like to consolidate them by event name and add their durations and keep the earliest timestamp

```
allEventList.GroupBy(e => e.Event)
        .Select(g => new eventRecords{
             TimeStamp = g.Min(e => e.TimeStamp),
             Event = g.Key,
             Duration = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(e => e.Duration.Ticks))
         });
```

This works by first grouping your list by `Event`, which gives you an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,eventRecords>>`. Then projecting these groups using `Select` to build up a new `eventRecords` with the desired properies aggregated as requested.

Live example: http://rextester.com/MTVNH46675

---

In answer to your comment, you can filter the list before grouping it using `Where`. For example, if you only wanted events where the length of the event name is greater than 5 (contrived example!)

```
allEventList.Where(e => e.Event.Length>5)
            .GroupBy(e => e.Event)
            .... etc
```

Comment: would there be a way to exclude items where Event = some key word?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
allEventList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Event)
    .Select(grouping => new eventRecords
                {
                    Event = grouping.Key,
                    TimeStamp = grouping.Min(entry => entry.TimeStamp),
                    Duration = new TimeSpan(grouping.Sum(entry => entry.Duration.Ticks))
                };
```

Maybe the `grouping.Min(entry => entry.TimeStamp)` could be replaced by `grouping.First().TimeStamp`. I don't know whether order is retained by `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
 var list = new List<EventRecords>();

 list.Add(new EventRecords{ TimeStamp = new DateTime(2014,1,1), Event = "1", Duration = new TimeSpan(1)});
 list.Add(new EventRecords { TimeStamp = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), Event = "1", Duration = new TimeSpan(1) }); 
 list.Add(new EventRecords { TimeStamp = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), Event = "2", Duration = new TimeSpan(1) });
 list.Add(new EventRecords { TimeStamp = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), Event = "3", Duration = new TimeSpan(1) });

 var output = list.GroupBy(e => e.Event)
            .Select(e => new EventRecords
            {
                Event = e.Key,
                Duration = new TimeSpan(e.Sum(ee => ee.Duration.Ticks)),
                TimeStamp = e.Select(ee => ee.TimeStamp).Min()
            });
```

For items with the same event name, sum their timespans:

```
new TimeSpan(e.Sum(ee => ee.Duration.Ticks)),
//create a new timespan from the sum of all timespan ticks
```

and grab their earliest timestamp:

```
e.Select(ee => ee.TimeStamp).Min()
```

Items with only one entry will remain unaltered

Answer (score 0):

I used the Northwind database, but this seems to do what you want:

```
from o in Orders
where o.CustomerID != "HANAR"
group o by o.CustomerID into ox
select new 
{
    Event = ox.Key,
    Start = ox.Min (o => o.OrderDate),
    Duration = ox.Sum(o=>o.Freight)
}
```